# My question was closed saying "not business professional" -- but my question pertains to my work

Tags: discussion

My question was closed saying "not business professional" -- but my question pertains to my work. Our database landscape is in AWS and Azure -- providing federal government projects.

You can see my question history, to see that this is not some homework assignment.

This is the URL to my question:
[Open an application with "runas a different user" by passing the username pop-up](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71075/open-an-application-with-runas-a-different-user-by-passing-the-username-pop-up)

Please reconsider.

Comment: How does the WINDOWS *runas* have anything to do with professional networking?

Answer (score 3):

Your question was closed because it it clearly off topic here, as was mentioned by Ron Maupin in a comment and as is explained on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. A suggestion where you *can* ask your question was provided as well.

I don't see any reason to reopen the question here, because this question is clearly about host configuration, so https://serverfault.com would be the appropriate place to ask this.

Comment: Thanks -- this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

> My question was closed saying "not business professional" -- but my
> question pertains to my work.

No, that is not true. The reason given for closure is:

> Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers, applications, and
> protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.

As pointed out in the comment, you could try to ask your question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) for a business network.

Comment: makes sense. I only saw the top banner and not your comment down below. Thanks for the suggestion.